# iOS Swift Scanning Multiple Barcodes

Tags: ios, swift, barcode-scanner

I use the following code to scan barcodes:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    var highlightViewRect = CGRectZero

    var barCodeObject : AVMetadataObject!

    var detectionString : String!

    let barCodeTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode,
        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
        AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
        AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,
        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code,
        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
        AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,
        AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode,
        AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode
    ]


    // The scanner is capable of capturing multiple 2-dimensional barcodes in one scan.

    for metadata in metadataObjects {
        for barcodeType in barCodeTypes {

            if metadata.type == barcodeType {
                barCodeObject = self.previewLayer.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadata as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject)

                highlightViewRect = barCodeObject.bounds

                detectionString = (metadata as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject).stringValue

                let len = detectionString.characters.count
                print("raw=\(detectionString)")
                if len == 25 {
                    detectionString=detectionString.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: detectionString.startIndex.advancedBy(3), end: detectionString.endIndex.advancedBy(0)))
                } else if len > 22 {
                    detectionString=detectionString.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: detectionString.startIndex.advancedBy(22), end: detectionString.endIndex.advancedBy(0)))
                }
                print("mod=\(detectionString)")
            }

        }
    }

    self.session.stopRunning()
    sendScan(detectionString)

    self.highlightView.frame = highlightViewRect
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.highlightView)

}
```

It looks like it should capture multiple barcodes from the same scan.  However, it only captures one.  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum number of simultaneous detections is 4, this number is only for 2 dimensional barcodes. 1 dimensional barcode recognition is limited to 1 detection. See this reference for more info:

[Apple: Technical Note TN2325](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2325/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013824-CH1-CAN_AVCAPTUREMETADATAOUTPUT_DETECT_MULTIPLE_1_DIMENSIONAL_BARCODES_IN_A_FRAME_//)

Running your code (for as far as provided), gets me multiple (2D) detections. Be aware that the sendScan method only sends the last detected item.

A slight modification to your code :

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    var captures : [String] = []

    for metadata in metadataObjects {

        var detectionString = (metadata as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject).stringValue


        let len = detectionString.characters.count
        print("raw=\(detectionString)")
        if len == 25 {
            detectionString = detectionString.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: detectionString.startIndex.advancedBy(3), end: detectionString.endIndex.advancedBy(0)))
        } else if len > 22 {
            detectionString = detectionString.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: detectionString.startIndex.advancedBy(22), end: detectionString.endIndex.advancedBy(0)))
        }
        print("mod=\(detectionString)")


        captures.append(detectionString)

    }

    print("Captured \(captures.count) barcodes.")

}
```

Produces this output:

```
raw=www.barcode1.co.za
mod=www.barcode1.co.za
raw=http://www.moxx.in
mod=http://www.moxx.in
raw=http://www.harrowhouse.com/
mod=.com/
raw=Ver1
mod=Ver1
Captured 4 barcodes.
```